# Drawing Two CNOT gates

Tags: circuits, tikz-circuit-lib, quantikz

I'm new to LaTeX and the tikz package in general. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{quantikz}
    \lstick{$\ket{x}$} & \ctrl{1} & \targ{} \qw \\
    \lstick{$\ket{y}$} & \targ{} & \ctrl{1} \qw 
  \end{quantikz}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And it outputed this: 
[image: Quantum circuit]
The second control is suppose to connect to the second target but I am not sure why it ended up like this instead. Any help will be great, thank you!

Comment: Welcome! This question is not related to `circuitikz` at all.... I suggest you remove the tag ;-)

Comment: @Rmano Sorry about that, it has been removed!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you complete your example to a compilable code? This way, it will be easier for others to help you.

Comment: @Vincent Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ctrl{-1}`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\begin{document}    

\begin{quantikz}
     \lstick{$\ket{x}$} &  \ctrl{1}    &  \targ{}     &  \qw \\
     \lstick{$\ket{y}$} &  \targ{}     &  \ctrl{-1}   &     
\end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just figured it out too, I feel so silly. Thank you!